# How can I search list only the directory?

Tags: linux, find

As all we know, we can search a file or directory in the linux by:

```
find / -name theName
```

But there shows all the files and directories and permission denied, like this bellow:

```
...
find: /Library/Caches/com.apple.iconservices.store: Permission denied
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.2-py2.7.egg/django
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.2-py2.7.egg/django/forms/jinja2/django
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.2-py2.7.egg/django/forms/templates/django
find: /Library/SystemMigration/History/Migration-389D835B-414A-4D8D-A683-7407624E87E8/QuarantineRoot/System/Library/DirectoryServices/DefaultLocalDB/Default: Permission denied
find: /private/etc/cups/certs: Permission denied
find: /private/var/agentx: Permission denied
...
```

If I just want to shows the directories find by the command, how to do with it?

Comment: So do you want to exclude all `Permission denied`?

Comment: Using a modern shell (ignoring portability for the moment), you can use `/**/theName/` instead of running `find` at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use

```
find / -type d -name theName
```

to only find directories whose names are `theName`.  Without `-type d` you will also test the name against regular files, sockets, named pipes etc. that are not directories.

This will still give you the same "Permission denied" errors, because you don't have sufficient permissions to enter those directories.

To ignore the errors, simply add `2>/dev/null` at the end of the command.  This will redirect the error stream to `/dev/null` (they will be thrown away).

Root probably has access to the directories that you can't get into, so if you have `sudo` access, you could try

```
sudo find / -type d -name theName
```

This will run the `find` command as the root user.

Comment: And there is a requirement, I don't want to show the permission denied, because they are too many, how to solve it?

Comment: @lustre As I said, add `2>/dev/null` after the command:  `find / -type d -name theName 2>/dev/null`